# Zend Framework 2 CLI

Tags: zend-framework2

I realise that the stable release of Zend Framework 2 hasn't been been out for long, but having been through the [skeleton tutorial](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html) it seems that there's a lot of work that needs to be done in order to get a new module working.

I'm just wondering if there are any tools available such as a CLI that make the creation of new modules/models etc easier.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new ZFTool module to create new module and application structures for you via the cli

https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool

Create a new module

```
zf.php create module <name> [<path>]
```

Create a new project

```
zf.php create project <path>
```

Comment: A little late, but the right answer to this old question.

Answer (score 0):

There probably will be tools to automate the creation of modules later on but probably not yet. Recall that the tools for autocreating projects for ZF1 didn't come out for quite a few releases. I'm not sure exactly which release but I think it wasn't until after 1.8 that the tools became available.

Until then, should DEFINITELY think about creating a 'skeleton' module and maybe putting it up on github or even create a pull request on the skeleton application to have your skeleton module, with the extra setup already done, added to the skeleton application or have it replace Zend's altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton module already exists on github. It's been there for months and updated regularly as zf2 developed.

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule